# How to make a default value as selected in an @Html.DropdownList in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

controller :

```
List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select--", Value = "-1" });
foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
    if (item["Name"].ToString() == abc) {
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item["Name"].ToString(), Value = Convert.ToString(item["id"]), Selected = true });

    } else {
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item["Name"].ToString(), Value = Convert.ToString(item["id"]) });
    }
}
```

I am using `Selected = true` but its not working

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like, is the option "selected" in the page source?

Comment: @Robert    it shows --Select-- when loading

Comment: Can you show us your html/razor code and the rendered HTML code in the browser (as Robert requested)? How are you passing your SelectList to the View?

Comment: Are you sure your conditional is being triggered?  Your SELECTED option is only being added when "Name" == a specific value.  If there isn't a matching name, you won't have a default selected value in your dropdown list.

Comment: You need to show how you generate the dropdownlist in the view. If your binding to a property then its the value of the property that determines the option that selected (the value of `Selected` is just ignored) - thats how model binding works. And adding the `SelectListItem` with `Text = "--Select--", Value = "-1"` is bad practice. Use the overload of `DropDownListFor` that accepts a label option.

Answer (score 0):

On your view, try something like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("myDD",Model.li,"---Select---")
```

or better:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idSelected, Model.li, "---Select---")
```

or even better:

controller:

```
viewModel.idSelected= -1;
```

view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.idSelected, Model.li)
```

Comment: you should use a viewmodel if using MVC, so set the selected id to your viewmodel "idSelected" and use dropdownlistFOR

Comment: i wanted   the foloowing to be as default :     li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item["Name"].ToString(), Value = Convert.ToString(item["id"]), Selected = true });

Comment: sorry, misunderstood you question, just check if  your var "abc" is set to any value, it shuld work